# Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[AuthService -> Http]:

Tags: angular, unit-testing

Error message appears during the tests:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[AuthService -> Http]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AuthService -> Http]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!
    at _NullInjector.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js._NullInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1003:1)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1301:1)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1243:1)
    at StaticInjector.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1111:1)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1301:1)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1243:1)
    at StaticInjector.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1111:1)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:10896:1)
    at _createClass (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:10935:1)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:10907:1)
```

my script **auth.service.spec.ts**:

```
describe('AuthService', () => {
  let injector: TestBed;
  let service: AuthService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule] ,
      providers: [AuthService]
    });
    injector = getTestBed();
    service = injector.get(AuthService);
    httpMock = injector.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  it('should be created', inject([AuthService], (service: AuthService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

Adding the `HttpClientTestingModule` class to imports does not help.
What should I do to fix the error in the tests?

Comment: The `HttpClientTestingModule` is meant to be used with the newer `HttpClient`, not the deprecated `Http`. Consider moving to `HttpClient`.

Comment: in my `AuthService` class, I use `HTTP` from the class `@angular/http`

Comment: What class I should use in the unity-tests, if I use in the `AuthService` class use HTTP from `@angular/http`